# How to mock a QML component

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, qml, qt5

Actually I'm trying to run some test on a [QML component which embeds C++ objects](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-contextproperties.html). Unfortunately, I'm getting some errors when I execute my tests. The C++ objects aren't recognized by the QML file. That makes also sense as the C++ objects are set in the main.cpp file.

My question is: How can I mock an context property for performing QML tests? Or other said, how can I do unit-test with mixing Qt/QML code?

Comment: How are you running your tests? Are you writing unit tests in QML and trying to use _qmltestrunner_ to run the tests? Are you trying to run QML inside C++ and run the tests from _googlemock_? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  I have the same problem.

Comment: I figured out something that worked and added it as an answer below.  Unfortunately, my original cry for help there was down voted; so I'm hoping someone will take another look and up vote the edited one back to life.

Answer (score 1):

I got QML tests working for me without compiling in any C++ code.

In my case, I have a C++ object *controller* with a property called *left_motor*, which is another object, and that has a property *speed*.

Note that *speed* is readable, but not writable.  Any updates will happen through slots.  In QML that looks like this: controller.left_motor.onGuiSpeedChanged(speed)

I was able to mock this in QML using Item components, properties, and some javascript.

> ```
> Item {                      // mock of controller
>     id: controller
>     property alias left_motor: left_motor
>     Item {
>         id: left_motor
>         property int speed: 0
>         function onGuiSpeedChanged(arg) {
>             speed = arg
>         }
>     }
> }
> property alias controller: controller
> ```

Now calls to controller.left_motor.onGuiSpeedChanged(speed) resolve like before, but connect into the mock function.  I can even read back the speed property to know that the call happened.

Here is my test function (the code I'm testing is part of page1):

> ```
> function test_set_speed() {
>     console.log("controller.left_motor.speed: " + controller.left_motor.speed)
>     var got = page1.set_left_speed(250)
>     compare(got, 250, "set_left_speed() return incorrect")
>     console.log("controller.left_motor.speed: " + controller.left_motor.speed)
> }
> ```

Note that it's important to use slots instead of writable properties.  The call to a slot looks just like a function call and can be mocked as such.  I could not figure out a way to mock out a property write.

I had started out trying writable properties because that was the first thing in the documentation on binding C++ and QML.  It connects QML and C++ as expected, but can't be mocked out for testing.

Comment: This space is for answers, any query you can do spaces similar to this one or create a new question.

Comment: My original request was misplaced, but I did find an answer and edited it to that.  I'm not sure the best action here:  either post a new answer (and leave the dead one), or edit the bad one (and have it have a negative score).  I did the latter, but welcome advise.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you right, you got same problem as I. Some time ago I wrote this mock: https://bitbucket.org/troyane/qml-cpp-template (you can use that code free for your purposes).

Take a look at `main.cpp`, there you can see two ways of doing things:

```
// 1 case:
// Register type and create object at QML side
qmlRegisterType<CppClass>("CppClassModule", 1, 0, "CppClass");
QQmlApplicationEngine engine(QUrl("qrc:///qml/main.qml"));
qDebug() << "Qt version: " << qVersion();
// 2 case:
// Create object here and "move it up" to QML side
// engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("cppClass", new CppClass);
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to move your C++ types to a [QML plugin](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-modules-cppplugins.html) so that the QML tests can import them. This plugin needs to be available to your tests at runtime, which means ensuring that they can be found in the [import path](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path). If you run into any issues with the plugin not being found, you can set the [`QML_IMPORT_TRACE`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-debugging.html#debugging-module-imports) environment variable to `1` to give you some useful debugging output.

However, even [QML-only test cases](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qttest-testcase.html#details) involve [some C++ to set them up](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquicktest-index.html#running-tests).

To execute C++ code before any of the QML tests are run, the [`QUICK_TEST_MAIN_WITH_SETUP`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquicktest-index.html#executing-c-before-qml-tests) macro can be used:

```
// src_qmltest_qquicktest.cpp
#include <QtQuickTest>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

class Setup : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Setup() {}

public slots:
    void qmlEngineAvailable(QQmlEngine *engine)
    {
        engine->rootContext()->setContextProperty("myContextProperty", QVariant(true));
    }
};

QUICK_TEST_MAIN_WITH_SETUP(mytest, Setup)

#include "src_qmltest_qquicktest.moc"
```

The most flexible and powerful option is to [write tests in C++](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qttest-index.html) and [load the QML from there](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtdeclarative.git/tree/tests/auto/quickcontrols2/qquickapplicationwindow/tst_qquickapplicationwindow.cpp?id=7255b7db30098a6290a0c7af74e3ca0258900e4b#n865).